# How can I listen for “remember me” reauthentication events in Symfony2?

Tags: authentication, event-handling, symfony, remember-me

Using “normal” — not “remember me” authentication — I can set a success and failure handlers, adding this to the `security.yml` file:

```
form_login:
    # ...
    success_handler: authentication_handler
    failure_handler: authentication_handler
```

But I couldn't find a way for listening for “remember me” reauthentication, when a user's session is expired and a “remember me” cookie is used to reauthenticate again. Any ideas on how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 5):

Create a Listener for the [`security.interactive_login`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/security/authentication.html#authentication-events) event. That gets triggered on both simple and "remember me" logins (see `Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall\RememberMeListener.php` @line:77).

In the listener you can separate the two by checking the cookie.
You can find more about the listener [here](http://www.metod.si/login-event-listener-in-symfony2/).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't need this feature now, but when I'll need it again I'll try your solution to see if it works.

Comment: I should note that this, while it work, does not give you access to the Response object.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this but maybe you could attach listener to `success_handler` but make sure you inject `SecurityContext` service via `<argument>` in service config.

Then, is soon as you enter you service method you do:

```
if ( $this->securityContext->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED') ){
    // I am remembered visitor
}else{
    // I am the new visitor
}
```

Again, this is just an idea but sounds like it could do...

Comment: The problem is that the `success_handler` attached to `form_login` is not being called when a user is being relogged in by a “remember me” cookie.