# Loading user locale when logging in automatically with remember_me token in Symfony 4

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

Using Symfony 4 I managed to have my users save their locale prefs in database and loading these when they "fully" log in (with login form).

But I don't see how to load the user's locale prefs when logging in automatically with remember_me token.

This is my UserLocaleSubscriber:

```
<?php

namespace App\EventSubscriber;

use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\SessionInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Event\InteractiveLoginEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\SecurityEvents;

/**
 * Stores the locale of the user in the session after the
 * login. This can be used by the LocaleSubscriber afterwards.
 */
class UserLocaleSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    private $session;

    public function __construct(SessionInterface $session)
    {
        $this->session = $session;
    }

    public function onInteractiveLogin(InteractiveLoginEvent $event)
    {
        $user = $event->getAuthenticationToken()->getUser();

        $token = get_class ($event->getAuthenticationToken());


        if (null !== $user->getLocale()) {
            $this->session->set('_locale', $user->getLocale());
        }
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            SecurityEvents::INTERACTIVE_LOGIN => 'onInteractiveLogin',
        );
    }
}
```

My LocaleSubscriber:

```
<?php

namespace App\EventSubscriber;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;

class LocaleSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    private $defaultLocale;

    public function __construct($defaultLocale = 'fr')
    {
        $this->defaultLocale = $defaultLocale;
    }

    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        $request = $event->getRequest();
        if (!$request->hasPreviousSession()) {
            return;
        }

        // try to see if the locale has been set as a _locale routing parameter
        if ($locale = $request->attributes->get('_locale')) {
            $request->getSession()->set('_locale', $locale);
        } else {
            // if no explicit locale has been set on this request, use one from the session
            $request->setLocale($request->getSession()->get('_locale', $this->defaultLocale));
        }
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            // must be registered before (i.e. with a higher priority than) the default Locale listener
            KernelEvents::REQUEST => array(array('onKernelRequest', 20)),
        );
    }
}
```

My services.yaml

```
    App\EventSubscriber\UserLocaleSubscriber:
    tags:
    - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: security.interactive_login, method: onInteractiveLogin, priority: 15 }
```

Any ideas on how to achieve this ?

Couldn't use [listen to remember_me in Symfony2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7995366/how-can-i-listen-for-remember-me-reauthentication-events-in-symfony2) as classes from example were deprecated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I listen for “remember me” reauthentication events in Symfony2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7995366/how-can-i-listen-for-remember-me-reauthentication-events-in-symfony2)

Comment: This is for Symfony 2, the security classes are changed in Symfony 4.

Comment: But the remember me seems to still send a `security.interactive_login` event. I don't have the time to test it myself sorry :/